# DDD - Aggregate with large relation that is part of invariant

Tags: domain-driven-design

Say I have two models

`Project` and `Task`

A project can have many tasks, but a project can only have one task with a status of `in_progress` at any time.

As far as I understand it, this is normally handled as part of a root aggregate's domain invariant

In this case however, the list of tasks associated with a project is potentially unbounded, so it doesn't really fit well in my opinion, but at the same time the project should control and maintain the aforementioned invariant

Any suggestions on how best to model this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a *relation* between project and task, which should be 1-to-1.

```
project inProgress task
```

And your constraint is that such a relation should be unique for each project

That in turn suggests that your Project API includes members like

```
TaskId currentTask()
void changeTasks(TaskId nextTask)
```